# Create 2 deployments out of 1 base with 1 kustomization.yml

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I would like to create 2 deployments out of the same base and all in 1 kustomization.yml. To be a bit more precise, we have 1 base deployment for multiple customer and make our changes inside the kustomization, so all customer has the same base. This works fine until our new customer needs 2 kafka exporter (not replicas).

I would like to use the same base and create out of this base 2 deployments with different args.

```
/base/
     /kustomization.yml
     /kafka-exporter.yml
     /....
/overlays/
         /overlay1/
                  /kustomization.yml
                  /kafka-exporter.yml
                  /kafka-exporter-passive.yml
                  /....
         /overlay2/
                  /kustomization.yml
                  /kafka-exporter-patch.yml
                  /....
```

/base/kafka-exporter.yml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-exporter
  name: kafka-exporter
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-exporter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-exporter
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: docker-token
      containers:
      - name: kafka-exporter
        image: XXXXX
        ports:
        - name: kafka-exporter
          containerPort: 9308
          protocol: TCP
        args:
          - "--kafka.server=xxxxxxxx"
          - --tls.enabled
          - --tls.insecure-skip-tls-verify
          - --tls.cert-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.crt
          - --tls.key-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.key
          - --refresh.metadata=60s
          #- "--topic.filter=DUMMY"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: tls-certs
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: "/etc/tls-certs"
        resources:
          limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 200Mi
          requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 100Mi
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 999
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          capabilities:
            drop:
              - ALL
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: tls-certs
          secret:
            secretName: xxxxxx
        - name: policy-volume
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 5Mi
```

/base/kustomization.yml

```
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ./kafka-exporter.yml
```

/overlay/kustomization.yml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: example
nameSuffix: -example
resources:
- ../base
patches:
  - path: ./kafka-exporter.yml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
  - path: ./kafka-exporter-passive.yml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
```

/overlay/kafka-exporter.yml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-exporter
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka-exporter
        args:
          - "--kafka.server="
          - --tls.enabled
          - --tls.insecure-skip-tls-verify
          - --tls.cert-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.crt
          - --tls.key-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.key
          - --refresh.metadata=60s
          - "--topic.filter=.*test*"
```

/overlay/kafka-exporter-passive.yml

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-exporter
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka-exporter
        args:
          - "--kafka.server=xxxxx"
          - --tls.enabled
          - --tls.insecure-skip-tls-verify
          - --tls.cert-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.crt
          - --tls.key-file=/etc/tls-certs/tls.key
          - --refresh.metadata=60s
          - "--topic.filter=.*something_else.*"
```

I tried to create a second patch yml and add it to patchesStrategicMerge in the kustomization.yml in the overlay, but this still creates only 1 deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same deployment name twice. Second one is replacing values of first one, that's because its deploying only one.

Try create another deployment with different name, and patch it under your overlays with another file.

Comment: so you mean to create a new deployment in the base and patch it in the overlay.
Thats exactly what I dont want because its only 1 customer and I need to deactivate the second kafka-exporter for the other customer.

Comment: I dont want to change the base at all